# How to destructure an object that might be empty

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I have an interface

```
interface Foo {
  name: string
  subject: string
  body: string
}
```

And a function that takes in `Foo | {}` where I destructure the properties and do things with them if they are non-empty

```
const doStuff = ({body, subject, name}: Foo | {}) => {
  const errors = [
    body?.trim() && `body`,
    subject?.trim() && `subject`,
    name?.trim() && `name`,
  ].filter(x => x);
  setErrors(errors)
  ...
}
```

the destructuring is not compiling because well...it might be an object *without* those properties. How on earth do I tell typescript that its cool, an I want those properties to be `undefined` in that case without resorting to `@ts-ignore` or `any`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the type `Foo | {}`, use `Partial<Foo>` instead. [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) makes all members optional which is effectively what you're trying to do.

```
const doStuff = ({ body, subject, name }: Partial<Foo>) => {
  ...
};
```